# How to unlock a VSS database

Tags: database, visual-sourcesafe

How do I unlock a VSS database?  One of our VSS administrators ran the "Analyze & Fix" routine and it has prevented user from checking out files.

Comment: I believe the procedure is called "Ditch VSS for...well...anything else".

Comment: @Adam Robinson - We are in the process of replacing our source control software with Subversion but in the meantime this is what we make due with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual SourceSafe -> Visual SourceSafe 6.0 Admin.

Then go to Tools->Lock SourceSafe Database->uncheck the "Lock all users out of Visual SourceSafe" check box.

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply delete the \data\loggedin\Admin.lck file and then you should be able to log in.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I spent hours looking for this solution!  When logging into VSS Administrator, I kept getting the error message, File \data\rights.dat is already open, even though it wasn't.  Users were getting the message that the Administrator locked the database, even though he didn't...